# Why is IndexOutOfBoundsException thrown

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Below code is throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException at line Field f = getField(counter);
Why is it being thrown ? Surely the field exists because I am looping based on fieldcount. Or is the list fields in the manager not gauranteed to be sequential? If this is the case how should I delete fields from a screen that are of type - MyButtonField

Thanks

```
        int fieldCount = getFieldCount() - 1;
        if(fieldCount > 1){
            for(int counter = 0; counter <= fieldCount ; ++counter){
                Field f = getField(counter);
                if(f instanceof MyButtonField){                 
                    delete(f);  
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it to see what value you're passing to getField()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified what `delete(f)` does, but if it removes it from the list of fields, then your "valid count" will effectively decrease.

To rewrite this somewhat *and* fix the problem:

```
for (int index = getFieldCount() - 1; index >= 0; index--){
    Field f = getField(index);
    if (f instanceof MyButtonField) {
        delete(f);  
    }
}
```

This will go from the *end* of the fields instead of the *start*, so it doesn't matter if you remove an entry and everything shuffles up - the items which shuffle up will be the ones you've already looked at.

Comment: 295K !!!!!!!!!! how come you have this much reputation?............. :-O.... It's too much.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Iterator for iteration then call the method remove().
Example:

```
        for(Iterator it = getFields().iterator();it.hasNext()){
            Field f = (Field) it.next();
            if(f instanceof MyButtonField){                 
                it.remove();  
            }
        }
```

The method getFields() has to return a collection of Field elements.

Comment: The original question does not specify it, but BlackBerry uses java-me, which does not have iterators - it has enumerations and enumerations do not support 'remove()'